# Hadoop - Splitting of files

Tags: hadoop2

I have just started learning hadoop and i have a question on how the splitting works. 
For example, i have a file like below with key value-

2 1121291290r5405454
1 2192949495959454454
2 121334883484585

So my question is , when the splitting will be done will that based on the block size or the record type. if its based on block size it might be possible that while splitting the key-value data might be separated and put in different blocks which will give the incorrect data.

Taking my file as an example - if the file is splitting into 2 blocks -

block 1 -------
2 1121291290r5405454
1 21929494959594

block 2--------
54454
2 121334883484585

So, here the key value relationship is gone and resulting in incorrect data. As far as i know the split happens when the input file size exceeds the block size. So how do we handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

By default ,number of input spilit depends upon the number of blocks. In your case , if there are two block for a single file , then two mappers will run . while writing the data into blocks , hadoop uses a kind of pointer which indicates the location of next block, so by using this pointer,  first mapper identifies the exact key value pair and process accordingly and  2nd mapper will start computation by leaving that data which will be processed by 1st mapper. Simply a map task is not limited to that block only, it can also process the data from other blocks.

Comment: Thanks Manish for the reply. My query is now clarified.